# Is there a way to prevent the Huawei PC Manager from sending my data to Huawei?

Tags: desktop-computer

When I was setting up my Huawei computer one could enable the setting that the Huawei PC Manager automatically installs driver updates if you are inactive. Since it was explicitly that you change it afterwards I didn't think anymore about it.

However this setting just restarts my PC from time to time without asking me. I don't want to uninstall the program because than I get performance warnings like "May shorten battery life", "less cpu power" etc.

I want to change it now with the Huawei PC Manager but now (that was their strategy) you have to agree to the Huawei policy terms and you have to do it online (so they can directly send it to Huawei). Is there another way to change it or preventing the PC Manager from sending my data to Huawei?

Comment: Why don't you just uninstall the software?  There is absolutely nothing unique about the program and is necessary since all drivers are installed through Windows Update.

Comment: I don't know who disliked my comment but I see nothing wrong about this question. If it would be as easy as uninstalling this program I wouldn't have ask. As you can see in my edited question I'm afraid to damage my computer when I Uninstaller the program. If there is anyone who knows a trick to bypass this problem I would be very thankful.

Comment: Winareo "One Click Firewall"  https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1841 "Blocks any app from accessing the Internet with one click". Here is the Apps section: https://winaero.com/winaero-apps/  A very good programmer for Windows 10, etc..

Comment: @MarcusBrodie - You cannot downvote and/or dislike comments.  The third-party application should be uninstalled. Removal of the Huawei spyware shovelware is a good idea

Comment: Try to use Windows Firewall(wf.msc), in advanced settings, click outbound rules, right click and create new rule, choose application rules, use path, you can get path by right clicking on shortcut, and then set action to block, then just save it and enable it, this sould do the trick; If you don't understand any of these, refer to online guides.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Windows 11 and did not get all the drivers from Windows Update. Mine is a 14s with MX350 GPU, and that wasn't detected, but it also got a generic display driver with a poor color profile, the fingerprint sensor wasn't working, and device manager showed ~10 or so "unknown" devices.

Huawei PC manager fixed that. But I too chose to keep my system up to date, thinking it would maybe integrate with Windows Update (if that's possible?) or at most run a lightweight background service that would occasionally check if any driver updates are available. Alas, it runs a whole bunch of services and also "Huawei Control Panel", which is just useless bloat in my case as I don't have any other Huawei devices.

I decided I'd rather not run it automatically at startup, but to keep it installed so I can run it manually to check drivers every few months, or if I have any issues. Luckily that's easy to set up, once you find it... they did hide it a bit.

The settings are found behind the icon left to the left of the minimize button.

> [image]

Once in there, the first setting in the "general" category is a toggle to run at startup or not.

Comment: Btw after Win11 I also installed Fedora 38 (Linux). The fingerprint reader doesn't work (but you can't do much with it on Linux anyway) and I had to turn on the "large text" accessibility feature as fractional scaling isn't available, but otherwise everything worked perfectly, and is faster, with less fan noise and better battery life on Fedora. Unlike in Windows it's peace and quiet, it never tries to steer you towards buying sh*t. Give Linux a try, or dual boot if you game as well.

Comment: Add new info to your answer by editing it, not by adding a comment.